# Unable to get pycharm to run my .sh file

Tags: python, bash, pycharm, sh

So I'm not sure how to word this correctly but I have a .sh file that I use to turn on my python app and it runs fine when I run this command ./start_dev.sh in my terminal. But I am having trouble trying to have it run in pycharm because my app is run in Ubuntu and I don't know how to direct the interpreter path to my Ubuntu virtualenv bash command. Is this even possible?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to go to `Run->Edit Configurations` and then add configurations, including an `Interpreter path` where you can set the path to your virtualenv bash executable

Comment: correct but only if you add the bashSupport plug-in (Pycharm-preferences-plugin-installJetbrainplugin..)